# PHP: окуругление

Tags: php

```
<?php
print (int)((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
?>
```

Почему получается 7 а не 8?

Comment: Возможно потому, что (int) не округляет, а отбрасывает дробную часть.

Comment: @alexlz, это так, но всё  гораздо хуже

    $v=(0.1 + 0.7) * 10;
    echo "$v\n";
    echo (int)$v."\n";
    echo (int)"$v"."\n";

[выдаст](http://ideone.com/LYL2wX)

    8
    7
    8

Comment: @eicto И чем же оно хуже? Не вижу ничего странного в примере. Хотя оно чем-то и напоминает рогатку с лазерным прицелом...

Answer (score 4):

Подробно все описано: [Раскладка float-а в памяти](http://crazycode.net/blog/1-php/36-ieee754)